# AndroidKeystore on 4.1 API

Tags: android, security, android-keystore, android-developer-api

I am using `AndroidKeystore` as the provider in my current project to store private keys securely.
Now I want to make my app available for older Android releases down to 4.1 (API version 16).
Therefore I need to find an alternative for the `AndroidKeystore` but can hardly find any usable solution.
Is there any recommendation how to implement/emulate/replace the `AndroidKeystore` functionality on these older versions?

Additionally the `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` is available since v18. What would be the correct replacement on older versions?

Comment: can you use BouncyCastle keystore instead ?

Comment: The AndroidKeystore is a provider for (preferrable) hardware security devices. The question is what to use instead. A plain KeyStore would be one solution.

Comment: I'm also incredibly flabbergasted that the support library doesn't provide backwards compatibility to Android 4.1. Seriously! I am at a loss for words. Maybe in a couple of years I'll get over it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a working solution.
For Android 4.x there is the Credential Storage service which can hold various secrets.
The best description I found so far is here

http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html

Comment: Did it worked with no issues? I read in this blog post that it is tested but not guaranteed to work.

Comment: I had no problems with it. Unfortunately there is no other "standard way" I found. So what can you do? Use and hope :-)